# Are synonyms evidence of cultural merges between ethnicities?

Tags: etymology, synonymy

The word "Chance" has a few translations to German: Chance, Zufall, Gelegenheit, etc. The German Chance is borrowed from Latin, where it developed from *cadere* "to fall". I can assume the word Zufall means also "to fall" (because that's the literally meaning of the word, if you break it zu-fall). So the existence of multiple words for the same concept definitely show some cultural exchange of the people speaking the language.

My question is can synonyms be used to show (or speculate) merges of ethnicities/tribes, etc? And are there any prominent examples of this?

EDIT: maybe a more concrete example are the words Lage and Schicht(ung) in German, both can mean "Layer", but the first origin is from Old High German, while the 2nd is from Old Low German. Could it be that some people used one word, other people used another, and with time and cultural exchange, both people started to use both words?

Comment: *Zufall* also translates *coincidence*, apparently with the same *cado*. However, what stumps me is that *zu* would look like a false cognate of *co-* given that *c-* had been used to render *z-* occasionally and that *c* before other vowels at least had become /s/. There are a few more coincidental *co-* ~ *zu-* analogies to be drawn. This is difficult to ignore. On another note, it might be misleading to associate all incidences of *-fall* with "to fall". Anyhow, one denotional sense of v. *zu-fallen* "to fall to" (i.e. inherit, win) might offer some intermediate insight. Thus I 2nd the Q

Comment: @vectory In most of Romance, C and G palatalized only before front vowels and /j/; in what would become French, also before /a/ (which may have been a front vowel [æ] at that point). I can't think of any Romance language that palatalized C before /o/.

Comment: that's why I said "occasionally". You are not saying *co-* were occasionally rendered with a high vowel or iotization? That would be quite the *coincidence* indeed.

Answer (score 4):

In Sanskrit there are [dozens and dozens](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?q=sun&lang=en&action=Search) of synonyms for 'sun', none of them a loanword. The same goes about other notions, too, generally speaking Sanskrit has very few loanwords, mostly names of plants and animals. A [dozen](https://www.sanskritdictionary.com/?iencoding=iast&q=spoon&lang=en&action=Search) words for 'spoon'. Could you, please, *definitely show some cultural exchange* that stood behind the unimaginable number of synonyms in Sanskrit, in a language with almost no loanwords?

I'd rather say that synonyms show the massive cultural background behind a language, a man who never makes anything with one's own hands doesn't need two words for "hammer".

Comment: What vectory said. If it has dozen of words for Sun, how do you know it's not infusion of many different tribes using different words for sun? To show this you would need to find and map all the languages that joined to make sanskrit. Of course it's not the only explanation, but surely for many words this could be the case.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli - Usually, languages split, not join.

Comment: @yellowsky, that's nonsense, not only because an implicit definition of joining is questionable, but rather because typological evidence cannot negate a specific instance.

Comment: @YellowSky I think languages split when cultures split, or become too far apart. But if cultures become closer, and unite, the languages follow.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli - I know no example when two cultures unite or when two languages join. The usual course of things in the real world is like this: when 2 cultures meet, one of them either absorbs some elements of the other or assimilates the other one, destroys it. The same with the languages. Either both remain or only one of them remains, but it's _never_ like both of them disappear and something new is born from the ashes.

Comment: *it's never like both of them disappear and something new is born from the ashes* - Is Modern English a continuation of Old English, or is it something new, born from the ashes of OE and Old Norman French ?

Comment: @LuísHenrique - Surely Modern English is a continuation of Old English which underwent influence from Old Norman. Old Norman didn't disappear either, it evolved through ages and was the ancestor of modern Norman, including the insular dialects (such as Jèrriais). This is the case when both languages survived their meeting, during which Old Norman, as the prestige language, influenced Old English.

Answer (score 0):

To me, your question merges a couple of non-related issues. Firstly, talking about synonyms is chiefly a matter related to a specific language and not a cross-linguistic one. Secondly, the fact that two different languages use a certain word with the same language-specific etymology for the same concept may be due to two phenomena:

-coin due to language contact, which is probably what you are alluding to.

-a similar pattern of conceptualisation, which is due to cognitive principles and has nothing to do with contact.

Comment: 3. semantic calque

Comment: What do you mean? We are talking about semantics here, so that's pretty obvious..

Comment: I mean you should know what a semantique calque is. *Fernseher* for example is modeled on the basis of *television*, but *fern* and *seh* have germanic roots. You have alleged this were a coincidence ... except, you might argue, Fernseher is not a synonym at all and a new concept needs new words. But It's also notable that the strict assumption, every word were either a synonym or not, leads to paradoxes (ask me about it).  Contrast *Mattscheibe* "silver screen", *Röhre* "tube", there are near synonyms.

Comment: Sorry, but you don't know what you are arguing about. Linguistics has nothing to do with creativity, which you perfectly master.

Comment: You still fail to answer the question. The OP has obviously shown--in a trivial sense albeit--that one particular loan can be used to identify culture clash. Working that out into a fully fledged answer is difficult, because analogy is the bain of etymology (paraphrasing Beekes 2011, intro to the comparative method, chapter 6)

Comment: Ok, then post a more qualified answer! What do you mean by "bain"?

Comment: I'd prefer a positive answer, but this slightly more complicated than just putting it down with a handwave.

Comment: s/bain/pane/; read: bread and butter, lol

Comment: No offence meant, but you are beyond the point in whatever regard.

Comment: I get you vectory, don't lose hope in humanity

Comment: Look, I really tried to help, but there's no preview for the book in google so you have to help yourself (I meant Ch. 7, by the way, and it doesn't really get around to loans except a few mentions in passing, because analogies in general are just banefull).

Comment: @Nico Most words have origin. For example in Hebrew, my native tongue, a lot of words have Akkadian origin. So are the synonyms. What I'm referring to is a situation where the synonyms can indicate some cultural fusion. Obviously ideas can spread and "infect" other languages without actual cultural assimilation, but I was thinking maybe there are some examples where it did.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli The fact that some words in a certain language go back to another language as a source has nothing to do with synonymy whatsoever, sorry.

Comment: @Nico the point is that you have 2 synonyms, but 1 comes from 1 origin, and the other from another. But ok, I understand you don't think this is any indication of cultural merging.

Comment: @DavidRefaeli This is not a site for sociological or ethnical issues. Besides, your question is not clearly formulated, as I have already pointed out.